# Azure rest api authentication

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication, azure-monitoring

I'm building an Android app that will access Azure REST API and read some data from azure monitoring.
I'm having problem on the authentication process because not sure is it possible to use MSAL library to authenticate to access Azure REST API?

Comment: Is it a native android app, a xamarin app ?

Comment: It is a native Android app.

Comment: So are you talking about this library ? https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android. If your REST API uses AAD auth, it should work

Comment: Yes, but what should I put for scopes so it can access Azure Monitor Rest API?

Comment: Could you post your existing code and a little bit more of context: what is blocking you ? what did you manage to do for the moment etc.. ? cheers

Comment: I'm using this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android .I don't know scopes that I should define so it can access Azure rest api? Is is possible using this library?
For example this api GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}?api-version=2016-06-01 and after this one from Monitor

Comment: sorry your first link return a 404

Comment: sorry, I edited  it

Comment: do you mean the web api app generated by azure? do you have the app generated by azure as well?

Comment: so have you tried with the scope defined in the sample: `final static String SCOPES [] = {"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"};` ?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I've created an app on the https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, not working

Comment: could you post some kind of errors ? what is the step that is failig in your code ?

Comment: I'm getting this error Unexpected response code 401 for https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2016-06-01

Comment: Put the error detail along with what you've tried in the text of your question to help future visitors determine if their problem is related. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

In your mentioned demo code that the resource is microsoft graph.
If you want to use Azure service management API, we need to change the resource to `https://management.azure.com`. And we need to [assign role to the registried Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-the-application-to-a-role).

I am not familiar with preview SDK, but we also could do that with following way to get the access token for Azure management API.

By default the V2 application is not displayed in the Azure portal. So we need to consent the permission. Then we could found it in the Azure portal.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/adminconsent?
client_id={clientId}
&state=12345
&redirect_uri={redirectUrl}
```

Then use the admin account to approve the consent. After that we could find the V2 application in the Azure portal and assign the role to application.

[image]

[image]
From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison), we could know that the v2.0 endpoint does not support [OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3).

So we could use the authorization code follow to get the access token.

1. get the authorization_code

   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)?
   client_id={clientId}&response_type=code
   &redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
   &response_mode=query
   &scope=https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
   &state=12345
2. get access token

   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)?
   scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
   &client_id={clientId}
   &grant_type=authorization_code
   &redirect_uri={redirectUri}
   &code =AQABAAIAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjT6o1ePh...

[image]

Test Accesstoken

[image]

Comment: What about tenant id if it's going to be a native app? How to get that?

Comment: It is not relate with the native or webapp app. If you want to access the azure resource then you should have an Azure directory, we could get the tenant id from azure portal. We also could use the `common` to instead of tenant id, if we use the v2 application. For more information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#scopes-not-resources)

Comment: Couldn't find solution with msal so backed to the adal. 
When use adal library it works when there is tenantId inside Authority url. But when use common instead of tenant id inside Authority url (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common) I'm getting error when trying to sign in.